# Good approach for my specific issue

Tags: java, android, sockets, server

I wrote a client(android smartphone)-server(java)-program.

It's just for practice and till now I am just sending a string to the server saving it to a file.

Currently I want to implement a new feature sending my gps coordinates every 5 minutes to my server and saving it.

For this I'd set up a `AlarmManager` receiving a broadcast every 300000ms (or 5 minutes).

When receiving a broadcast I wanted to establish a connection to my server:

**AlarmReceiver.class:**

```
    public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("alarmReceiver","received alarm");
        MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) context;
        activity.cConnect = new ConnectionThread(activity.clientServer, activity.out);
        activity.cConnect.start();
    }
```

}

**ConnectionThread.class:**

```
    public class ConnectionThread extends Thread {

    Socket clientServer;
    BufferedWriter out;

    public ConnectionThread(Socket clientServer_, BufferedWriter out_) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.clientServer = clientServer_;
        this.out = out_;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.run();
        try {
            clientServer = new Socket(MainActivity.dstName, MainActivity.dstPort);

            out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientServer.getOutputStream()));
            out.write("alarm received"); //currently just sending this string
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            clientServer.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Where in my **MainActivity.class** I declared the following:

```
protected static String dstName = ...
protected static int dstPort = ...
public Socket clientServer;
public BufferedWriter out;
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private static int repeatAlarmEvery = 30000;
private static int firstAlarmAfter = repeatAlarmEvery;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);...
```

My Problem is, that I am afraid I am trying to transmit a text while my `AlarmReceiver` received a broadcast and already has established a connection on the same port.. So I decided to have only one `socket-object called clientServer` and this way I can check if `clientServer != null` -> `do not establish a new connection, instead use the existing one`.

But trying to run the my client-program on my emulator I am getting following error:

```
06-03 19:24:29.969: E/AndroidRuntime(2186): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext cannot be cast to com.example.clientservercommunication.MainActivity
06-03 19:24:29.969: E/AndroidRuntime(2186):     at com.example.clientservercommunication.AlarmReceiver.onReceive(AlarmReceiver.java:14)
```

What I think/see is that the context received by the broadcast is restricted and I am not allowed to cast it to my activity `MainActivity`. So I am not able to access `clientSocket` and `out` from `MainActivity.class`.

Now I have two solutions in mind:

**1)** Declaring `clientSocket` and `out` static.

**2)** Establish a different connection (different port) for text transmitting avoiding conflict between transmitting text and gps coordinates. e.g. text transmitting port 50000, gps data transmitting on port 50001

**Question:**

Which one is the better(regarding memory leak if there could be any etc., **not regarding opinion e.g. because I like the solution better etc.**)/ more common approach or is there any better design pattern/solution to achieve what I want.

It is very important for me to get support about the right pattern because I am sick of trying it without enough background knowledge running into tons of problems. Hope I described my issue well.

Comment: The received `Context` in the `BroadcastReceiver` is not an instance of `MainActivity`. Hence the `ClassCastException`. Why don't you move your `Socket` and related instances into another class that doesn't need an instance of `MainActivity`?

Comment: I am thinking about creating a whole new `holder-class` which just holds the socket and the bufferedwriter. When receiving an alarm I am creating an `instance/object` of this particular class and accessing the socket and the bufferedwriter. Did you mean that? @nhaarman

Comment: @nhaarman Ok this can not work because I would need to access from different classes to that instance of the holder class. I am currently testing with static socket and bufferedwriter and it looks good till now ! Please elaborate your comment more.

Comment: We cannot see how you try to send a text. If on the same port than you could still use another connection. Then the server has to resolve the situation receiving text and coordinates at the same time over two connections.

Comment: @greenapps sure you can see.. right now I am just sending a text in ConnectionThread now just think that the run method is fired when clicking on a transmit text - button. The implementation of fetching the gps coordinates is my last task of this new feature. Yeah your idea was my second solution in my mind as stated in my question, but is there anything bad about the solution declaring clientSocket and out as static and just set a flag if the transmition of e.g. string has finished and gps coordinates can now be transmitted over the same con.?Mostly I am concerned about gaining a memory leak.